# Multiple arguments in single option using getopt()

Tags: c

following is my code to use options using `getopt()`. Now, I want to provide multiple arguments to a single options, for which I used `atoi(atgv[i])`, where i= 2,3,4,..... My code obviously works with the following command line : `./a.out -m 7 3 -f 1 4 5 -M 3 6 5 1`
  but obviously won't work with `./a.out -f 1 4 5` or `./a.out -M 3 6 5 1` or `./a.out -f 1 4 5 -M 3 6 5 1` or `./a.out -m 7 3 -M 3 6 5 1`  . I tried using `optarg()`, but it accepts only single argument for a given option. So, how can I provide multiple arguments to a single option? It's not necessary that I need to use `getopt()`. My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int opt;
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,x;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "mfM:")) != -1) {

switch (opt) {


case 'm': 
a= atoi(argv[2]);
b= atoi(argv[3]);
c=a+b;
printf("The sum is: %d\n",c);
break;

case 'f':
d= atoi(argv[5]);
e= atoi(argv[6]);
x=atoi(argv[7]);
f=d+e+x;
printf("The sum is: %d\n",f);
break;


case 'M': 
g= atoi(argv[9]);
h= atoi(argv[10]);
i=atoi(argv[11]);
j=atoi(argv[12]);
k=g+h+i+j+k;
printf("The add is: %d\n",k);
break;


 default: //default case
 fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-f or -m or -M] filename\n", argv[0]);
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   }        

  }
}
```

Comment: Invoke program as `./a.out -f "1 4 5"` (assuming Bash), then use `strtok_r()`, and finally **indent** your code.

Comment: Or support a comma-separated input: `./a.out -f1,4,5`.

Comment: @trojanfoe if I use comma separated input what should I write for values of g,h,i,j which I was using as `atoi(argv[9])`, `atoi(argv[10])` and so on.

Comment: @H2CO3 can you show a example, it's not clear to me

Comment: @user227666 The example was `./a.out -f "1 4 5"`...

Answer (score 1):

A construct like:

```
case 'm': 
a= atoi(argv[2]);
b= atoi(argv[3]);
```

defeats the whole purpose of getopt().

If you have a command with getopt() that specifies parameters "mfM:", it means that you are OK with someone specifying either

```
program -m -f -M 3
```

or

```
program -f -M 3 -m
```

and so on.

Second, if you want multiple arguments to a single option and you want to use getopt, you should really be specifying:

```
program -M 3 -M 4 -M 5
```

and so on.

Here's how I would rewrite your program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  int opt;
  int mv = 0, fv = 0, Mv = 0;

  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "m:f:M:")) != -1) {

    switch (opt) {

    case 'm': 
      mv = mv + atoi(optarg);
      break;

    case 'f':
      fv = fv + atoi(optarg);
      break;


    case 'M': 
      Mv = Mv + atoi(optarg);
      break;

    default: //default case
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-f or -m or -M] filename\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }        
  }

  printf ( "-m sum %d\n", mv );
  printf ( "-f sum %d\n", fv );
  printf ( "-M sum %d\n", Mv );
  return 0;
}
```

And run it this way.

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ ./go -m 3 -m6 -m 14 -f 2 -M 1 -M6 -M12 -M 18
-m sum 23
-f sum 2
-M sum 37
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$
```

Comment: it's not necessary that I need to use getopt(). Is there some other efficient way to do it?

Comment: getopt() is certainly the most widely used mechanism that I know of and I would use it whenever I have anything but the most trivial command line. Maybe there are other frameworks that support other mechanisms but I'm not familiar with them. 

I think it is the most efficient way for you if repeating the command option is acceptable.

Comment: actually I want to perform other operations also rather than only addition, like the start and mid of for loop like this: for(g=atoi(argv[9];g>=atoi(argv[10]);g=g+atoi(argv[11]))).So, this mv or fv or MV won't work for this cases.

Comment: getopt() is free to permute your command line so relying on ordinal position is a bad idea. for what you are looking for (the start, end and step in a for loop), I would recommend you consider making each one a command option -s <start> -e <end> -S <step> or some such thing. 

As a meta issue, if you were to state your question more completely; i.e. provide the "complete requirements", it would help provide you a "complete answer" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I have manage to do to palliate this problem ; as "optagr" point on an arg_v, we can advance it by his length to access the next one :

`pointer arithmetic :: av[i + 1] = av[i] + len(av[i])  + 1`

we continue until we stumble opon a '-' for the first character of the buffer ;

then we secure it ,in case nothing is following it, by checking if it's equal too the first element of the env (who, as papy used to says, follow argv in the memory) this the "char *limit" part

```c
int manage_op(char op, char *opt_arg, server_t *server, char *limit)
{
    int i = 0;

    switch (op) {
        case 'n':
                for (char *buff_name = opt_arg;*buff_name != '-' && (strcmp(limit, buff_name));
                buff_name = buff_name + strlen(buff_name) + 1)
                    server->teams_name[i++] = strdup(buff_name);
                server->teams_name[i] = NULL;
        case 'x':
            server->x = atoi(opt_arg);
            break;
        case 'y':
            server->y = atoi(opt_arg);
            break;
        case 'f':
            server->freq = atoi(opt_arg);
            break;
        case 'p':
            server->port = strdup(opt_arg);
            break;
        case 'c':
            server->nbr_max_per_teams = atoi(opt_arg);
            break;
    }
    if (server->port == -1)
        exit(84);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    server_t *server_v = malloc(sizeof(server_t));
    int op;

    if ((ac > 1) && (!strcmp(av[1], "-h")  || !strcmp(av[1], "-help"))) {
        printf("%s", HELP);
        return 0;
    }
    server_v->teams_name = malloc(sizeof(char *)* ac);
    while (op = getopt(ac, av, "p:x:y:c:f:n:")) {
        if (op == -1)
            break;
        manage_op(op, optarg, server_v, env[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0;server_v->teams_name[i]; i++)
        printf("%s\n",server_v->teams_name[i]);
    //server("8000");
    return 0;
}
```